# How to make the current window blur with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, window, blur

I would like to blur the current windows after 3s when the page is loaded. How to make the current window blur with jQuery?

I am not detecting the blur event.

====updated===

I tried:

```
$(window).blur();
$(document).blur();
```

Failed

====updated===

I mean un-focus the current window / page of the browser.

Comment: show us your code. what have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by *blur* - A *visual blur* or *unfocus* ?

Comment: I tried:
$(window).blur();
$(document).blur();

Failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
var xSeconds = 2; // 2 seconds
var myDialog = $('dialog_element').dialog('open');
setTimeout(function() { myDialog.dialog('close'); }, xSeconds * 1000);
```

Comment: Your idea is interesting, not that I want but love to know.
However seems the code is not working...

Comment: **The testing code:**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var xSeconds = 2; // 2 seconds
var myDialog = $j('dialog_element').dialog('open');
setTimeout(function() { myDialog.dialog('close'); }, xSeconds * 1000);
</script>

</head>

<body>
<p>Testing page</p>

</body>
</html>